# Is there a field of math dedicated to understanding irrational numbers

Tags: irrational-numbers, irrationality-measure

I have an interest irrational numbers and want to understand them. Is there a specific field for it?

Comment: I'd say algebraic and/or analytic number theory. These are rather vast and diversified fields, though. Irrationality measure specifically, if I'm not mistaken, should be a topic of *Diophantine approximation*.

Comment: @Gae.S. What about just understanding them generally? Like what is the pattern of irrational numbers on the number line (e.g. rt2 rt3 and so on) and why? What would a visual representation of irrational numbers look like? And most importantly of all how is it possible we can have a number with infinitely many decimals place?

Comment: I don't quite see how having infinitely many decimal places should be considered an issue of irrational numbers, since most rational numbers have that characteristic too. It has been known for millennia that division of integers cannot be calculated exhaustively by adding finitely many decimal (or sexagesimal) digits.

Comment: I mean you can have as many decimals places as you like there is no question about that, however I think there is a difference between being able to have as many decimals you like and literally having a number with infinitely many decimal places such as sqrt2. Surely this is something worth understanding?

Comment: $\frac17$, $\frac13$, $\frac1{110}$ et cetera have infinitely many decimal places, them being $0.\overline{142857}$, $0.\overline 3$ and $0.0\overline{09}$ respectively.

Comment: @gae. S. But whose to say 1/3 etc can be expressed in decimal form? Maybe it could be argued that you cannot express 1/3 in decimal form for base 10 but you can for base 9 where 1/3 would simply be 0.3. Just playing devil's advocate. Looking for a rigorous proof.

Comment: It is certainly true that for any real number $x$ the following are equivalent: (i) $x$ is rational; (ii) there is a digit-expansion basis $b$ such that $(x)_b$ is a recurring expansion; (iii) for all digit-expansion basis $b$, $(x)_b$ is a recurring expansion; (iv) there is a digit-expansion basis $b$ such that $(x)_b$ is a recurring expansion with periodic part $0$.

Comment: $(i)\Leftrightarrow (ii)\Leftrightarrow (iii)$ is standard (and the parts that really need proof are $(i)\Rightarrow (iii)$ and $(ii)\Rightarrow (i)$). As for the weird one out, $(i)\Rightarrow (iv)$ by choosing $b$ to be the denominator of the fraction (unless it is $1$, in which case it is trivial); $(iv)\Rightarrow (ii)$ is a tautology.

Comment: Also, every real number has a digit expansion in every basis.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no, understanding irrational numbers is not a topic studied as a branch of mathematics.

Many (elementary) texts discuss the cardinality of the set of irrationals (there are more of them than rationals) and ways to find some (infinite decimals that don't repeat, [approximating irrationals by rationals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_approximation) ).

There are open questions about particular numbers - for example, we suspect but don't know that $e^{\pi}$ is irrational. Those questions are often deep and difficult.

Comment: Do you know of any mathematicians who try to understand why we can have numbers with infinitely many decimal places? I understand there is proof such as pythagorus' theorem when the hypotenuse is sqrt2, but surely we can deepen our understanding of irrational numbers. Not just in the sense of proofs showing that sqrt2 cannot be rational either, but really digging down and understanding the 'mechanics' behind it if you will.

Comment: @ShannonT Mathematicians have dug down that way a lot, so we know a lot about irrational numbers. But there is no single person or place I can refer you to. If you search for _irrational numbers_ you will find many links. Some should lead to material elementary enough to tell you some of what you want to know.